# Why am I getting an intermittent CORS error from an unchanging origin on Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting this error intermittently in the browser console when I try to do a jQuery.post()

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-myId.cloudfunctions.net/myFunction?q=query'  from origin 'https://ALWAYS-THE-SAME' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Most of the time I don't get the error. I have this in my Google Cloud Function:

```
exports.myFunction = (req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.set('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```

If I run the code causing this error again on the same page I may get no CORS errors. It seems completely intermittent.

**update:**

I also notice this error before most if not all of the CORS errors:

> POST https://us-central1-myId.cloudfunctions.net/myFunction?q=query
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 500

Comment: Just a thought, but it could be as a result of the request hitting different servers or server instances when cloud hosted? Maybe something to look into

Comment: If you get a 500 error then you need to find out what the error is. Consult the server side logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that exceptions in my function caused these errors to show up in the browser console. I fixed the exceptions and the errors went away. It seems like it was an improper error description.